# Drawing polygons with fixed area?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3, area

[image: Example01]

I am looking for a way to draw polygons with a fixed area. I am currently mapping farming options on field parcels. Some areas such as buffer strips run along features like rivers and hedgerows so they have easily mappable fixed lengths but I also need to create a fixed area for the feature which would govern the width. As hedges and rivers are rarely straight and farmers like to farm to straight lines the perimeter needs to be adjustable to create the most efficient use of space. Using QGIS 2.8.3 and ArcMap 10.3

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify the GIS software in use.

Comment: any way you could draw an example or something? i'm having a hard time following what you're after.

Comment: "buffer strips run along features like rivers and hedgerows so they have easily mappable **fixed lengths**" --  Given the fixed length, won't then a fixed buffer distance off of your river or hedgerow features give the area you need?

Comment: By specifying two Desktop GIS products you are effectively asking the same question for each (i.e. two questions).  I think your question is more likely to be answered if you focus your question on one or the other and include a single question mark somewhere in your question body.

Comment: This question is interesting and challenging, despite its difficulties in fitting the SE format in its current state. @user23715 creating a buffer of fixed area for a multi-segment line is not trivial.